# how to get the name of current host?

Tags: macos, ssh, hosts

This may be a pretty dump question!

So how do I get the host name so that I can ssh into my machine (which is a Mac)?

For instance : `ssh myusername@<hostname>`
Is there any command to find out the hostname from the terminal?

[Edit]
So I was able to find the host (thanks to your help! :) ). But I'm still getting 'Connection timed out' when trying to ssh into the machine. 
Actually, I can ssh into my machine from the VM that shared the same connection with this machine. Is there anything else (firewall option/etc) that I need to change to completely enable remote-login?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Tried entering `hostname` in your Terminal?

Comment: I need a command that obtains the full <hostname> when entered on the remote session. For me hostname does not return <hostname> but an abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

check under system preferences->sharing, when you enable remote login on your mac it will tell you right there what user and hostname to use.

Comment: Thanks! So I turned on the remote-login option. But when I tried to ssh from a different account, I keep getting connection timed out. Do you happen to know what else I need to change/re-configure in order to completely enable remote-login ?

Comment: As far as I know that is all you need, however Remote Login must either be set to all users or have the user you want in their list. I would expect you need to have a password set for that user as well.  On my computer for instance, my user is vextorspace and my ip is 192.168.1.112 and my domain is macbook.local so I can either do an ssh vextorspace@192.168.1.112 or ssh vextorspace@macbook.local. The only things I have set under sharing are remote login and remote management. remote management is for vnc access.